# puts e p em Ruby

Tags: ruby

Qual é a diferença entre `p` e `puts` no Ruby?

Quando eu deveria escolher usar um ou o outro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os dois mostram representações diferentes de um determinado objeto na saída padrão da aplicação. O **`puts`** mostra a representação legível por humanos mais padrão fazendo a chamada do método `to_s`, enquanto o `p` faz a chamada do método `inspect` que é mais voltado para fins de *debug*.

## TL;DR;

### [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p)

Faz a chamada do método `inspect` e escreve o resultado na saída padrão. Por exemplo: `p foo` a saída será o retorno de `foo.inspect`.

É mais útil pra *debug*, pois o método `inspect`, por padrão, é voltado para esta finalidade. A implementação *default* dele é retornar uma `string` com o nome da classe e uma lista de todas as suas variáveis de instância e seus respectivos valores (o `inspect` também será chamado para todas estas variáveis).

Exemplo em código:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @foo = 1
    @name = "foo"
  end
end

@foo = Foo.new
p @foo
```

A saída será algo como:

> ```
> #<Foo:0x0055da22ac5c40 @foo=1, @name="foo">
> ```

### [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)

Faz a chamada do método `to_s`. Aplicando ao exemplo acima, `puts foo` imprimirá o retorno de `foo.to_s`.

Tomando como ponto de partida a classe `Foo` definida acima, a saída de

```
puts @foo
```

Será algo como:

> ```
> #<Foo:0x0055da22ac5c40>
> ```

---

- [Documentação do método `inspect`.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect)
- [Documentação do método `to_s`.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-to_s)
- [Documentação do `puts`.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)
- [Documentação do `p`.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p)